# Load the latest folder from azure blob storage to azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I have a scenario where I have to fetch the latest folder from the blob storage container and then process all files under that folder through Azure data factory,  currently, all folder name based on timestamp and as we know CloudBlobDirectory don't hold LastModified Date so there is no way to extract metadata from Azure data factory activity like last modified time so that I can iterate with the timestamp and process the content.

[image]

Is there any other way to perform something like sort on the folder name and then pick it based on string sort (on folder name )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried something similar using Azure functions.

Please have a look and tell if its of use.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eUMjghIEsjw